# Using passport-docusign on nodejs

Tags: node.js, passport.js, docusignapi

I am attempting to connect docusign on my app using nodejs and passport.

Requirements:

- the docusign authentification is required only for few actions
- a user can have multiple docusign connections
- I would like to store the docusign token on my db, not only in session

Context:

- I have already an other strategy with passport to authenticate my users (using bearer token in the headers of each request).

Is the library passport-docusign really suitable for these requirements or
it makes more sense to create something custom?

Someone which has the experience of this kind of use case would have any advice on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [passport-docusign](https://github.com/docusign/passport-docusign) strategy for passport is pretty vanilla.

If passport works for your use case, then the passport-docusign strategy should be of help with implementing the authorize code grant flow.

If you find changes/updates that could be made to the passport-docusign strategy, please add an issue or pull request to the repo.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I did not manage to resolve my issue.
The problem is in the oauth uri callback, I don’t know which user has initiated the authentification(I am using bearer token in headers for authentification), so I cannot link my existing account with the docusign account. Is there a way to resolve this kind of problem?

Comment: Yes, use the OAuth state parameter to maintain state via the authentication flow. Or use your web framework's session library. Or save a cookie, or use local storage.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my issue with the oauth state containing a nonce token.